# Can't serve CSS in Nginx

Tags: html, css, nginx

I have a `/dist` folder which is build after an `npm install` etc. (Angular).
I place this folder in `/usr/share/nginx/html/`. So I'm using Nginx to host.

My `nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }    

http {   
        upstream node-app {
              least_conn;
              server nodejs:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;

        }

        server {
              listen 80;

              location / {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dist/;
                index index.html;
              }

              location /api {
                proxy_pass http://node-app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
        }
}
```

The API is working. It looks all fine. But in my browser, I can only see my HTML and my images. But I can't see my CSS.
While my network is telling me:

`main.css` this request had no preview available. But the GET works and is returning a 200.

But when I click twice on it I get a new tab with the css-code.

The CSS is in my `/dist/assets/css/main.css`.

When I don't use the nginx.conf but I only put the dist folder in

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/
```

and nothing else. Than I'm able to see the executed css on my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this means that anything written in the file mime.types is interpreted as if it was written inside the http { } block.

```
http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `location` block to something like this:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html/dist;

location / {
     index index.html;
}
```

(Please note, we have also moved the `root` block above the `location` block so that it can be available everywhere)

Comment: I edited my nginx.conf like you said but still the same issue.